# Trouble Parsing JSON return with variable

Tags: javascript, parsing, axios

I am having difficulties getting past part of a return from a function.
Below is my code that calls the data, this is also available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dubinsky-kn3s3?file=/src/App.js

You will see the data returned in a JSON, where the company name is nested under data.
Currently, I can get this data using `const testData = JSON.stringify(table.data.AAPL.wacc)`, but this isn't very efficient as I would like this: `const testData = JSON.stringify(table.data.<ENTER SYMBOL>.wacc)`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const Valuations = () => {
  const [table, setTable] = useState([]);

  const response = {
    method: "get",
    url: "https://marketciapi.io/api/market_dcf/AAPL/detail/",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Token 5ce1831cd7a3b411ded718500cb14ed2a2f5a464",
    },
  };

  Axios(response).then((response) => {
    setTable(response.data);
  });

  const testData = JSON.stringify(table.data);

  return <div>{testData}</div>;
};
export default Valuations;

// JSON Return: {"id":3,"slug":"AAPL","name":"AAPL","data":{"AAPL":{"wacc":9.41,"dcf_value":84.85,"avg_tax_rate":25.45,"cost_of_debt":2.36,"cost_of_equity":22.57,"debt_percentage":63.25,"cashflow_forecast":{"next_year":{"FCF":70367568,"NWC":-2674058,"ebit":91751958,"CAPEX":13977149,"ebit_tax_shield":68258846,"inc_depreciation":13411813},"next_2_year":{"FCF":68901308,"NWC":-5556810,"ebit":85980227,"CAPEX":15340264,"ebit_tax_shield":63964968,"inc_depreciation":14719794},"next_3_year":{"FCF":80412341,"NWC":-10890204,"ebit":94365405,"CAPEX":16836315,"ebit_tax_shield":70203119,"inc_depreciation":16155334},"next_4_year":{"FCF":84528412,"NWC":-8226164,"ebit":103568342,"CAPEX":18478268,"ebit_tax_shield":77049642,"inc_depreciation":17730875},"next_5_year":{"FCF":88793424,"NWC":-5049838,"ebit":113668792,"CAPEX":20280352,"ebit_tax_shield":84563869,"inc_depreciation":19460069},"current_year":{"FCF":101247000,"NWC":-18780000,"ebit":88400000,"CAPEX":7309000,"ebit_tax_shield":78720000,"inc_depreciation":11056000}},"equity_percentage":36.75}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
const companySymbol = 'APPL';
JSON.stringify(table.data[companySymbol].wacc);
```

Comment: This works fairly decently, however, I am having issues where the second part of the function is not waiting for the name. Any idea how to fix this? possibly with an asynchronous load?

Comment: You would block the render then, which is not a good idea, you're going to need to put the data fetching part into a `useEffect` hook, and wrap the `stringify` part into a condition.
`if (table.data) { const testData = JSON.stringify(table.data); return <div> {testData}</div>; } else { return <span>loading...<span>; }`